# AMAZON.TIME issue in Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": ... // my current intent name
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "StartTime",
          "type": "AMAZON.TIME"
        },
        {
          "name": "EndTime",
          "type": "AMAZON.TIME"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using AMAZON.TIME slot type for time slots. The problem is that in one of my slots, Alexa cannot handle data properly.
Details - When I said "1pm" in EndTime slot, Alexa knew it was "13:00". But, in StartTime slot, it only returned "00:00", sometimes didn't return any response.
I did every step exactly the same on both slots.

Comment: 1. Are you typing the text in the Alexa Simulator or using it by voice?

2. Did you provide atleast 5-7 utterances with proper Start and End time slot assigned properly?

Comment: 1. typing text in Simulator. 2. Do you mean Intent utterances? Actually, my intents are imported using json from Lex. For intent utterances, I've already assigned properly. I found user utterances field inside each slot. Do I need to add some utterances in that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're typing the text in Alexa Simulator, Alexa is unable to parse your text properly and thus it is not recognizing your Start time and End time.

In Alexa Simulator, try using by voice, there's a mic image - Press and hold it -> Then tell your response -> then release the mic image. This will solve the issue.

**Why this strange behavior?**

Let's see an example: Say you're working on a weather app and want to know the weather of London between 10 AM and 2 PM. So in Simulator you type:

> Tell me the weather in London between 10 AM and 2 PM

Now, when you say the above response but now in voice, Alexa will interpret it as:

> Tell me the weather in London between ten am and two pm

According to `AMAZON.TIME` [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#time), `ten am` will become `10:00` and `two pm` will become `14:00`. But your typing text `10 AM` is little strange to `AMAZON.TIME` and thus it doesn't recognize it properly.

To make this `10 AM` working, you'll need to define your own custom slot and then work on it on your code manually. **But**, when in production, end users will call your app using voice, so when user says `10 AM`, Alexa will send `ten am` as slot value to your app and your app may break. So I **don't** recommend this method.

Alexa is built using/for voice experience, so testing it with voice utterances makes more sense than just typing.

Comment: Yes, should use voice utterances. Thanks a lot.